# Multiple regression analysis

Tags: r, multiple-regression, count-data

I have a data set based on 14 field sites, the dependent variable I am investigating is count data recorded at each site (on 3-5 visits).  The independent variables (I have around 45) are fixed at each site (apart from wind speed and temperature).  An example data set, illustrating this is below:

```
            Trees    water   butterflycount 
Site 1      6        8       3

Site 1      6        8       12

Site 2      3        3       8

Site 2      3        3       0
```

What is the best way of preparing this kind of  data for a multiple regression analysis in R?  Would data1.glm = glm(butterflycount ~ 1, data = data1, family = poisson) and the working through adding the lowest AIC valued variables to the equation work?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you observe a site more then once? Is Trees the number of trees at this site? Is water the measurement of the water-quality?

Comment: Sites are observed more than once, on different dates e.g. visit one there were 3 butterflies recorded, visit 2, 12.  Trees would be the proportion of land covered by trees and water would be the proportion of land covered by water.

Comment: The observations of trees and water are nested within each site but do not change between measurements. If the impact of trees and water on butterflycount is supposed to be analysed you could think about using a design which can deal with random effects. But since you only have two observations/site I would suggest looking at plots first, then try something like glm(butterflycount ~ 1+trees+water, data = data1, family = poisson) though you would need to specify an offset value as well.

Comment: I have 14 sites and something like 45 variables.  Each site has between 3-5 visits but I can't and don't wish to put my whole data set online.  The data a gave was merely and example. :)

Comment: So depending on the question which is supposed to be analysed I would also try out a mixed effects model. The corresponding R function is lme4.